# Generate .txt files within specific range in a subdirectory using python

Tags: python

I am trying to generate text files by catching user input as the range for the generated files:

```
first_uid = int(input("Please enter first UserID and press enter: "))
last_uid = int(input("Please enter last UserID and press enter: "))

for i in range(first_uid, last_uid+1):
    f = open(str(i)+".txt", 'w')
    f.close()
```

however, it stores the generated files in the parent directory. I have tried to add

```
curr_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
r_path = os.path.join(curr_dir, r'\results')
```

and modify `f = open(str(i)+".txt", 'w')` to `f = open(r_path, str(i)+".txt", 'w')`, but `open` only accepts two arguments.

How could I make my code to generate the text files in another folder rather than the parent directory?

Comment: You may need: [`os.chdir`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-chdir-method/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the issue.

```
first_uid = int(input("Please enter first UserID and press enter: "))
last_uid = int(input("Please enter last UserID and press enter: "))

for i in range(first_uid, last_uid+1):
    f = open(f"result/{i}.txt", 'w')
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed that I was converting my int type to string!

Comment: That wasn't really the issue, you should read up on [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) in Python though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use os method and create your required dir using mkdir function.

Kindly find your solution below

```
import os
first_uid = int(input("Please enter first UserID and press enter: "))
last_uid = int(input("Please enter last UserID and press enter: "))
os.makedirs('result')

for i in range(first_uid, last_uid+1):
    f = open(f"result/{i}.txt", 'w')
    f.close()
```

For detailed path like abc/xyz/pqr/ you can use `os.makedirs()`